# Is the following pattern acceptable?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to come up myself with an acceptable pattern for  data reading from DB using Enterprise Library. How do you consider the following pattern (I mean, the null-check in the `finally` block)?

```
IDataReader NewReader = null;

try
{
    NewReader = (SqlDataReader)(SqlDatabase.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand));

    /* Do some work with NewReader. */

    NewReader.Close();
}
catch /* As much 'catch' blocks as necessary */
{
    /* Handle exceptions */
}
finally
{
    if (!ReferenceEquals(NewReader, null))
    {
        NewReader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is this null-check acceptable, or is there a more elegant way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `if(NewReader == null)`. It's the default way of checking for `null`. Your way of doing it is the same, but it looks strange and thus might confuse people.

Besides: Why don't you use `using`? Makes your code a lot cleaner:

```
try
{
    using(IDataReader NewReader = (SqlDataReader)(SqlDatabase.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand)))
    {
        /* Do some work with NewReader. */
    }
}
catch /* As much 'catch' blocks as necessary */
{
    /* Handle exceptions */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as:

```
if (NewReader != null) ...
```

which I would prefer from a styling point of view.

**Update:**

As `NewReader` seemingly implements `IDisposable`, just wrap it in a `using` construct.

Example:

```
using (var r = new ReaderSomething())
{
  try
  {
  }
  catch {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer using the "using" block as:

```
using(<your reader object>)
{
   //read data from reader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit of detail to what people have said above...

Use a using block as, regardless of whether an exception occurs or not, the Dispose method will automatically be called due to implementations of IDataReader having to also implementing IDisposable.